# Using EmberJS, Mocha and Karma

Tags: ember.js, bdd, mocha.js, karma-runner

I am using Mocha and Karma for writing and running test cases for my emberjs client. I bundle all my test cases as a single file and using minispade.js to solve the dependency issues

The problem which I am facing is that, I am able to run the test cases, but if a test case fails, it only shows the description of the test case and does not provide any info about the file which has the case written.

Is there any way to show the file name also, if any test case fails?

Comment: Update: Since, I am using chai assertion library, I was able to turn on the stack trace using the command: chai.Assertion.includeStack = true

Comment: phkavitha, are you able to share how you were able to use minispade together with karma?  I have tried darn near everything to get them to work together but my test files cannot see any of the variables defined in my minispade modules even though I'm successfully loading them.

Answer (score 0):

@stevekane,

Are you invoking your client's code ( ie. minispade wrapped files) in your test-case module using minispade.require()?

Here is how I have used minispade with karma:

1. I will bundle all my client's code  & test cases separately into a single file. Example: client.js & test_cases.js.
2. I will have  a separate file(say test.js)where I will declare some global which will be used for running my test cases . In this file, I will also invoke my client's code and test- cases using minispade.require().Here is how my test.js file will look:

   ```
      mocha.setup({ ui: 'bdd', ignoreLeaks: true });
      var assert = chai.assert; ........
      window.minispade.require('app/main'); // Client's code
      window.minispade.require("spec/main"); // Test cases
   ```

   Here main.js refers to a file where I have included all my  client &
   test cases modules using  minspade.require().
3. In karma configuration file, I will include test cases code under files. My configuration file will have the following lines:

> ```
>     files = [
>              {pattern : 'test_cases.js', included: true},
>              {pattern : test.js', included: true}
>           ].
> ```

4 Run the karma run command.

Hope I have made myself clear. Do try it and let me know if you get stuck.